# Upgraded spring-boot/spring-framework to 2.x.x/5.x.x for Spring Batch Java project and now data not being written/saved to Database (Postgresql)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-batch

I recently upgraded/migrated my Spring Batch Java application from `spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.9.RELEASE` to -> `spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4.RELEASE`, which subsequently pulls in the 5.X.X (5.2.3.RELEASE to be exact) springframework dependencies (before I was using 4.X.X). Some of the main ones I'm using are:

```
spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4
spring-boot-starter-batch
spring-boot-starter-jpa
spring-boot-starter-web
hibernate-core
hibernate-envers
hibernate-entitymanager
postgresql
```

For context, my application reads in .csv files and parses out the data and simply writes it to a postgresql database.

***After many hours of debugging today***, I know see that my first call to write data to the database, which is done by a JpaRepository method called `saveAll()`, which basically takes an ArrayList (Iterable) of Entities and batch inserts them to database, is **failing** somewhere when it enters the `JdkDynamicAopProxyClass` from the Spring AOP library. Previously, I was using the `save()` method, but this didn't work anymore once I upgraded my dependencies.

I know its failing here because I debugged meticulously and see that once it hits the `saveAll()` method in my java class that implements the `ItemWriter<S>` for Spring Batch, it enters the `public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)` method in the `JdkDynamicAopProxyClass`, and ends up throwing an exception, after doing a huge weird loop in the  library code that's hard to follow.

I also debugged my old Application that **WAS WORKING** when it was running on `spring-boot-starter-1.5.9` as I stated previously, and I see that when it gets to that `public Object invoke()` method (I mentioned above), it returns an ArrayList of the entities (which is correct) to write to the Database when it hits this line of code inside that method:

```
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
   // code here...

   // this is where I notice a difference in return type from the "working" code vs. "broken 
   // code"
    retVal = invocation.proceed();

  // more code here...

  Object var12 = retVal;
  return var12;
```

**HOWEVER**, when I debugged my new migrated code (that was upgraded to spring 2.X.X/5.X.X, I see it returns a `DefaultTransactionStatus@14037` object, which clearly is wrong. It then enters the `protected TransactionAspectSupport.TransactionInfo createTransactionIfNecessary()` method in the `TransactionAspectSupport` class from the `spring-tx` library. It will then have the `retVal` variable in the `invoke` method I mentioned above equal to `null` and it will start looping a few times more, over the same parts of code in a circle. It will have the `txInfo` set as `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE`. I can click the "Step Into" button in IntelliJ and it will let me step through forever. Its like a infinite loop.

I'm not sure what to post, or if there are any clues here. I googled and found other people have similiar issues, and it seemed to revolve around (possibly) the transaction manager or entity manager and how the Beans were setup in the configuration class.

I tried everything I read, but nothing worked. I'm not an expert with Spring Batch or Spring so maybe I am missing something here.

I also noticed when I was debugging my working code, it had a variable `Target = SimpleJpaRepository@11243` and it had some properties like a ArrayList of Providers

```
 Em = Shared EntityManager proxy for target factory [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@6f2b608e]
 Provider = HIBERNATE
 org.hibernate.Session [0]
 org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManager [1]
 org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager [2]
```

The odd thing was when I debugged my "broken" code, it seemed to only have the `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManager` in its List in this variable

If anyone can please let me know if there are some clues pointing to something, I would immensely appreciate it. I really think its a Bean config, Entity Manager/Transaction-issue, but I'm not an expert so I'm not sure. I thought it was a dependency issue at first, but after being on google that changed my mind.

Comment: You seem to be using Hibernate to persist data. Which transaction manager did you configure Spring Batch to use? Please share your configuration to be able to help you in an efficient manner, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I will update the configuration code right here

Comment: `I will update the configuration code right here`: That's not what I see, you have created 2 other almost duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67096340/basicbatchconfigurer-has-protected-access-spring-batch-spring-boot-not-persi, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103265/hikaricp-not-configuring-datasource-or-adding-postgres-connection-after-updating. Those are all related to the same issue of upgrading your project. It is not efficient to spread the details here and there.