# "BasicBatchConfigurer" has protected access - Spring Batch/Spring Boot not persisting data to database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I recently migrated my spring boot/batch Java application from spring-boot/spring-framework (respectively) 1.x.x/4.x.x to => 2.x.x/5.x.x (2.2.4/5.2.3 to be specific). The problem is something is definitely wrong (in my opinion) with the transaction/entity manager, as when the `.saveAll()` method is called from the `JpaRepository` class of my database persistance layer, it jumps into the SpringAOP framework/libarary code and into a infinite loop. I see it returning a "DefaulTransaction" object from a method (invoke()). My application on 1.x.x/4.x.x when it worked, would return the actual ArrayList here of my entities. I am using `spring-boot-starter`, `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, `spring-boot-starter-batch`, and `hibernate`/`hibernate-envers`/`hibernate-entitymanager` (also of course many other dependencies, let me know if you would like me to list them).

After some research, I'm finding people are saying that Spring Batch `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation sets up a default transaction manager, which if I'm using JPA could be causing issues. Reference:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2363

**wilkinsona** suggested defining this Bean in my `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(DataSource dataSource, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new BasicBatchConfigurer(dataSource, entityManagerFactory);
}
```

I'm getting an error when I do this because its saying the `BasicBatchConfigurer()` has protected access. What is the best way to instantiate this?

I also saw some people saying removing the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation fixes the persistance to database issue, but when I remove this, I lose the ability to Autowire my **JobBuilderFactory** and **StepBuilderFactory**. Is there a way to remove the annotation and get these objects in my code so I can at-least test if this works? Sorry, I'm not completely a master with Spring Batch/Spring.

In my `@Configuration` class, I am using the `PlatformTransactionManager`. I am setting up my JobRepository something like this.:

```
@Bean
 public JobRepository jobRepository(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                                @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDatabaseType("POSTGRES");
        return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
```

I can provide any other information if needed. Another question is - if I was using the same code basically, transaction manager, entity manager etc.. how was old my code working on 1.x.x? Could I have a wrong dependency somewhere in my pom.xml such that my new migrated code is using a wrong method or something from the wrong dependency?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `@EnableBatchProcessing` configures Spring Batch to use a `DataSourceTransactionManager` if you provide a `DataSource`. This transaction manager knows nothing about your JPA context. So if you want to use a JPA repository to save data, you need to configure Spring Batch to use a `JpaTransactionManager`.

Now in order to provide a custom transaction manager, you need to register a `BatchConfigurer` and override the `getTransactionManager()` method, something like:

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
        @Override
        public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
            return new JpaTransactionManager();
        }
    };
}
```

This is explained in the [Configuring A Job](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig) section and in the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html) of `@EnableBatchProcessing`.