# HikariCP NOT configuring Datasource or adding postgres connection after updating spring-boot 1.x.x => 2.x.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, hikaricp

I recently updated my spring-boot/spring-batch application from spring-boot-starter 1.5.9.RELEASE (uses spring-version `4.3.13.RELEASE`) => 2.2.4.RELEASE (uses spring-version `5.2.3.RELEASE`. The 1.5.9.RELEASE was using `Hikari 2.6.3`; I did try this version also in my migrated/updated `2.2.4.RELEASE` version of my app. `2.2.4.RELEASE` uses `Hikari 3.4.2` **Neither seem to work.** I am using `postgresql 42.2.9`

This is how the Hikari logs to my console ***when it works*** (when running the `1.5.9.RELEASE` spring-boot version of my app):

```
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.223 WARN  CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, setting to default 1800000ms.
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.223 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - configuration:
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.224 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - allowPoolSuspension.............false
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.224 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - autoCommit......................false
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.224 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - catalog.........................none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.224 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionInitSql...............none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.224 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTestQuery.............none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.224 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTimeout...............60000
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.224 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSource......................none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.224 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceClassName.............none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.224 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI..................none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - driverClassName.................none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties...........{}
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry.............none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - idleTimeout.....................600000
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - initializationFailFast..........true
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - initializationFailTimeout.......1
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries..........false
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbcUrl........................."jdbc:postgresql://mydatabaseurl.mywebsite.com:5432/supercooldatabase"
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold..........0
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maxLifetime.....................1800000
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize.................5
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricRegistry..................none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricsTrackerFactory...........none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - minimumIdle.....................5
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - password........................<masked>
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - readOnly........................false
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - registerMbeans..................false
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - scheduledExecutor...............none
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - scheduledExecutorService........internal
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - threadFactory...................internal
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.225 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - transactionIsolation............default
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.226 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - username........................"mktgoffers_ddladmin"
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.226 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - validationTimeout...............5000
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:58.226 INFO  CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:59.377 DEBUG CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@14ed7ddf
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-09 05:10:59.379 INFO  CorrelationId=
                    [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
3c22fb53ed64 2021-04-15 01:04:40.021 INFO  CorrelationId=
                    [main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
```

You can see it configures Hikari with my connection information and shows the jdbc url and even adds the postgresql connection.

This is how it looks when it **does NOT work**, after I updated to spring-boot `2.2.4.RELEASE`:

```
2021-04-15 01:14:11.681  INFO 75096 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-15 01:14:12.748  INFO 75096 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-15 01:14:12.760  INFO 75096 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
```

As you can see, its different. Normally I wouldn't care about logs, but when any of my `JpaRepository` methods get called like `.saveAll()`, the application hangs/stops doing anything and never writes to database. I was perplexed after first, and thought it was my Transaction/Entity manager setup in Spring-batch, but as I said before, all my code/configuration actually works perfectly fine (writes to database) on `1.5.9.RELEASE` spring boot. Now, I just discovered this database config in the log, and I'm 99% sure my database connection isn't even initializing properly.

Here is my **application yaml** (this is a snippet, but has all relevant info to database connection):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: My Super Cool App
  profiles:
    active: "myLocal,myLocalDev"
  batch.job.enabled: false
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximumPoolSize: 5
      connectionTimeout: 60000
      max-lifetime: 20000
      auto-commit: false
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc.batch_size: 5000
        order_inserts: true
        flushMode: COMMIT

---

spring:
  profiles: myLocal
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://database-main-url.mywebsite.com:5432/cooldbname
    username: mysuperkewluser
    password: hahasupersecretpw
```

And my definition for my database configuration, **DatabaseConfiguration.java**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment envVar;

    @Autowired
    private KeyVault keyProvider;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(
            prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari"
    )

    public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {

        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");

        String dbPassword = keyProvider.getKeyProvider(dataSourceProperties.getPassword());

        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create(dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                .password(dbPassword)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I am using this `@Autowiring` this dataSource in my Spring Batch `JobRepository`, which is defined in my **BatchConfiguration.java** class

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
   // Autowiring of the JobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory here

 @Bean
        public JobRepository jobRepository(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource); // dataSource
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDatabaseType("POSTGRES");
        return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();

// more business logic code here
}
```

Comment: This is the 4th time within 24h you are asking the **same** question in a different form. Please don't. Instead of asking all these questions in different incarnations I strongly suggest to read the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) for [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki) and the different frameworks you use. You are jumping 3 to 5 major versions and things have changed considerably. So please read those guide instead of asking the same thing over and over.

Comment: I helped dozens of people however I do want an answer when I ask for more information. Instead of people opening a new question with the same question and without additional information. But alas. imho you have asked the same question and you are still running into upgrade issues, those issues are related to newer versions, different properties and you just didn't read the upgrade guides.

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't know about that guide and you didn't post it in any of my earlier posts. I am reading it now thank you

Comment: +1 to what M.Deinum said. I also came to the same conclusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67086995/upgraded-spring-boot-spring-framework-to-2-x-x-5-x-x-for-spring-batch-java-proje#comment118615867_67086995. Big Bang migrations like this are never recommended. You need to migrate one major version at a time and read the migration guide each time.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was able to try every version and find that 2.2.0 works but -> 2.2.1 fails. I was able to upgrade to spring-batch-core 4.2.3.RELEASE manually (2.2.0 uses spring-batch-core 4.2.0.RELEASE) but I had to update jackson-databind or it did the Same thing where my first JpaRepositor method call .saveAll() doesn't persist any data to postgres db and applications is running, but just hangs/sticks (upon debugging, looks like it jumps into infinite loop in the Spring AOP/TX classes and I see weird stuff with the transactions). What's the logical step forward here? would like to find solution